# Javascript scroll issue in Opencart theme

Tags: javascript, html, opencart

I'm working on a project based on Opencart with the theme Tranda Social (I think it's deprecated). The problem I'm facing is that at Home page ONLY I can't get the scroll-effects (eg. When scrolling-down keep the navbar in fixed position, or getting to the TOP by just clicking the button with the UP-arrow). After some research I've concluded that for some reason a Javascript function isn't get called correctly.

```
setTimeout(function () {

    /* Menu */
    $('#menu ul > li > a + div').each(function (index, element) {

        var menu = $('#menu').offset();
        var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();
        i = (dropdown.left + $(this).outerWidth()) - (menu.left + $('#menu').outerWidth());
        if (i > 0) {
            $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + (i + 5) + 'px');
        }
    });

    /* Fixed Menu */
    $(function () {

        var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
        if (!msie6) {
            var top = $('#bottomh').offset().top;
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (y >= top) {
                    $('#bottomh').addClass('bottomfixed');
                } else {
                    $('#bottomh').removeClass('bottomfixed');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(function () {

        var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
        if (!msie6) {
            var top = $('#bottomh').offset().top;
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (y >= top) {
                    $('#bottomh').addClass('bottomfixed');
                } else {
                    $('#bottomh').removeClass('bottomfixed');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    /* Margin Menu */
    $(function () {

        var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
        if (!msie6) {
            var top = $('#bottomh').offset().top;
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (y >= top) {
                    $('#container').addClass(' topmargin');
                } else {
                    $('#container').removeClass(' topmargin');
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
        if (!msie6) {
            var top = $('#bottomh').offset().top;
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (y >= top) {
                    $('#container').addClass(' topmargin');
                } else {
                    $('#container').removeClass(' topmargin');
                }
            });
        }
    });
}, 500);
```

The functions after fixed-menu and margin-menu comments are NOT working when I'm navigating in Home page. Also if you notice, there is a duplicate of each function (don't know for what reason). Have you any ideas? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those function are supposed to do something **only in Internet Explorer 6** - are You sure You are visiting the site with such crap browser?

Comment: @shadyyx `if(!msie6)` completely opposite of what you were thinking :)

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal True, I missed that `!` sign... My bad :-(

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply, I've managed at last to resolve this. I noticed in console in Chrome that there was a Javascript error with a possibly unrelated component, the Slideshow module (nivo slider). Uninstalling-reinstalling it fixed the problem... :/ Thank you all for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem caused by Slidesshow module (Nivo Slider) because of a JS error related to it. Uninstall-reinstall the module fixes the problem.